# Data Visualization Prototype (Java/Eclipse/DAO/Relational DB)

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, web-applications

I am building a prototype application which displays various 2D & 3D data charts. I am using a third party library for the charts, the database and data extraction layer have already been coded.

Can you advise on a good desktop Framework to use within Eclipse to provide a 'professional' looking GUI with minimum coding required (This is just a prototype).

Further can anyone advise an effective method to port this application to a web server so users could access remotely? I have limited experience with GWT, are their more suitable alternatives?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on your third-party charting tool. Is it based on Swing or SWT? You're already eclipse and eclipse offers the eclipse RCP framework.

A new (prototype) application can be based on one of the RCP examples/templates. And there is a Swing-to-SWT bridge if you want to create an SWT based application but use Swing based components.

And eclipse offers some ways to build a rich client and a web app on almost the same code base with almost the same look and feel (eclipse RAP and/or the new e4 platform).

But all of them might take some time to learn the basics.

Comment: Sounds ideal, the re-use of code for Desktop and Web App would be very attractive. I will research RCP fully.
Many thanks

Comment: I don't think the RAP platform will ever support the Swing integration bridge, thus, it will not be possible to take this application online as a "native" web application. You could deploy it as a Java applet: this may be OK if you have a limited, predefined audience, but not for mass market.

Comment: @zvikico - this me be the case, but as I said, framework recommendation should be based on integrability of the third party libraries. They could be based on SWT/JFace, then it would be pretty diffcult to integrate them into a Swing based framework...

Comment: Thanks all, reading through the documentation it appears that the library has pre-defined bridge to AWT, SWT, or Swing. 

For the web app, it would be ideal to reach a larger initial audience allow them to get a 'look' and 'feel' of the application. If successful, this project would progress into a commercial quality SDLC.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which library are you using?